# httpclient android

Tags: android, httpclient

```
HttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://www.yahoo.com.hk");

        HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(post);

        if(rp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            String str = EntityUtils.toString(rp.getEntity());
            Log.e("STRING:",str);
            }
```

It is not printing error message also. It is giving launch timeout warning. Give me the code to connect with yahoo or google servers.

Comment: Give me the  code!!!At least show us what have you done.

Comment: Your code is correct.  Your launch timeout warning is probably the issue and probably has nothing to do with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine.
I'm not doing it much different.

> it is giving launch timeout warning.

Could it be that you are running this in the UI-thread instead of it's own thread?
Do you have the INTERNET-permission in your app?
Try adding a log-statement for the ELSE -case too.

Comment: thanks. internet permission was given. I put it in separate thread. But again there is no output. i gave else condition also. nothing is printed in logcat. any other way????